# How to add an additional edge between nodes that already have edges?

Tags: python, networkx

I have a `Graph` object and between each pair of nodes that already has an edge, I would like to add an additional edge? Is there a way to do this without brute force looping through all the edges?

Comment: Can you clarify?  The question in your title doesn't seem to match what you've asked here.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now, but if not let me know. The proposed answer below helps answer my first question.

Comment: Hi - to get a good answer, you really need to stick to one question per "question".  Can you refine this into separate questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is:

```
temp = nx.Graph(our_graph)
new_graph = nx.MultiGraph(temp)
new_graph.add_edges_from(temp.edges)
```

Comment: Why do we need to use the temp variable? For example, why wouldn't the following work: our_graph = nx.Graph(our_graph) ; new_graph = nx.MultiGraph(our_graph) ; new_graph.add_edges_from(our_graph.edges)

Comment: That would work fine too if don't need the original graph later.